Pattern matching for a repeated pattern (but different matching elements)
Is there a nice syntax for a pattern that is repeated (but it should match when the matching elements are different).
I mean something like
f[all : (i_Integer ..)] := {all}

But instead matching for example {1,2}.

I understand that in this case I can just write i__Integer but I am looking for something that would work for a more complicated pattern
f[all : (complicatedPattern..)] := {all}


So that was stupid. I think I was just looking for i__?(someTest). So I guess that answers this.

@Domen, well I thought I was not. Since I want something more complicated than testing for a head. But now I realize I was stupid and you are right. I was simply looking for i___?(someTest). Oops.

(My original comment): Are you looking for BlankSequence? Namely, f[all : (i__Integer)].

@Domen, Is it correct that if I have some complicated pattern I am forced to use a test rather than directly match a pattern? I.e. i__?MatchQ[pattern] rather than a more direct syntax like i__: pattern.

Can you please give an example of such complicated pattern?

@Domen, E.g. i__?MatchQ[{_Integer,_String}]

Why not just func[list : {{_Integer, _String} ...}] :=... or func[args : {_Integer, _String} ...] :=...

@lericr, thanks those indeed do what I want. I'm just confused why. What is the difference with the example I first tried. There it only matches if there is not just a repeat of Integers but specifically the same integer. That made me think this was generally the behavior. Now I don't understand why f[1,2] doesn't match in my example, but func[{1, "a"}, {2, "a"}] does in your example.

In f1[all : (i_Integer ..)]:= you have multiple nested patterns. The (i_Integer ..) bit is interpreted as Repeated[Pattern[i, Blank[Integer]]]. So, what's being repeated is a pattern that is bound to a specific name, i.e. i. So it's a bit like f[i_Integer, i_Integer]:=.

Imagine that instead of the example definition you gave we altered it slightly: f2[all : (i_Integer ..)] := {i, {all}}. Now, if you expected f2[1,2,3] to match, what value should i be bound to on the right hand side?

@lericr, thanks! Okay so this question was based on a simple misunderstanding on my part. I didn't think about the i binding. (Also in my real case I had left over bindings like that that I was no longer using now that I had decided to match all with a repeated pattern.)
